# Remove Photo/Video Switch in standard UIImagePickerController in order to force user to only take picture

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to find a way to hide the switch inside the standard overlay of the UIImagePickerController (the one at bottom right) because I want to force use to only take picture and not video.
Is that possible to do it without creating a custom overlay?

Thanks
Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/mediaTypes

I think that you just limit the mediaType as per above

Comment: Thanks, that's work perfectly and do exactly what I want. Thats the actual code if someone have the same problem: 

    mypickerController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];

It also important to add an import for: 

    #import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>

and add MobileCoreServices.framework in the project.

Thanks Again